# Sencha store update, refresh view

Tags: store, sencha-touch, extjs

When I add items to a store, I want an other page (that shows all items from that same store), to update / re-render the view so the new added items show up.

How can I 're-render' a view so re-checks a store for updates. Or something similar reload a view when an item is added to a store.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you update the Store events should be fired the DataView items (Lists, etc) that use that store and they should update automatically. Is that not the behavior you are seeing?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the DataView class. The documentation contains examples of what you want to do:
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/docs/?class=Ext.DataView